# Cannot access the Cisco ASA 5505 from ASDM

Tags: router

I have a Cisco ASA 5505 appliance. I have reset it to the factory default settings via CLI. I am able to launch the ASDM. But the ASDM is prompting me for the username and password. There is no default username and password for the ASDM as far as I know, if the ASA has a default configuration.
But still the ASDM is not allowing me to access the ASA.
I have tried some default credentials like cisco, root, admin etc. but nothing worked. The http server is enabled on ASA.

How can I access my ASA via ASDM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem was that I didn't have any enable password set. Although I had reset the device many times to factory default but still I was not able to login into the device due incorrect login credentials. OR it could be that I have to set an enable password to use the ASDM. So I just configured a new enable password on the ASA and then I was able to login via ASDM with the specified password.

This link will help. https://supportforums.cisco.com/document/79016/asa-password-recovery

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't tried using the default CLI try that, if no luck. There could be many reasons, not using the right ADSM image, no enable password, HTTP/https server not enabled.

Log into the CLI using the standard Cisco default user/password and then setup a user account make sure you setup an enable password and also check the https server. If this isnt set its most likey the cause.

Follow this post:

https://supportforums.cisco.com/discussion/11290531/how-configure-asdm-cisco-asa-5505